# Is there a Perl equivalent for Ruby's Regexp.names?

Tags: regex, perl, capturing-group

In Ruby you can extract the named captured groups of a regex using the `names`method:

```
/(?<foo>.)(?<bar>.)(?<baz>.)/.names
#=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Is there a Perl equivalent for such method? I could extract the names doing something like this:

```
while ( $re =~ m/\?<(.+?)>/g ) {
    say $1;
}
```

But I don't know how robust/efficient/elegant that solutions is.

**EDITED**: I know that you can get the names after a match but I need to extract the names before using the regex.

Comment: I don't understand what the Ruby one does. You can have named capture groups in Perl.

Comment: what you need is probably `keys %+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [PPIx::Regexp::capture_names](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPIx::Regexp#capture_names):

> ```
> foreach my $name ( $re->capture_names() ) {
>       print "Capture name '$name'\n";
>  }
> ```
>
> This convenience method returns the capture names found in the regular expression.

I have not tried this module, so I am not sure if it is a 100% reliable way extracting the information you want.

See also @ikegami's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11851336/100754) which led me to re-read [perldoc re](https://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#Exportable-Functions):

> `regnames($all)`
>
> Returns a list of all of the named buffers defined in the last
>           successful match. If `$all` is true, then it returns all names defined,
>           if not it returns only names which were involved in the match.

So close, yet not quite. I am not aware of a builtin way of doing introspection on regular expression patterns in Perl in the way Ruby's `.names` does.

Comment: Thank you! That was I was looking for.

Comment: Note that this requires the regexp pattern to be parsed seperately as a `PPIx::Regexp` obiect. It will not work with an ordinary compiled Perl regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the names of the groups after a successful match:

```
my $re = qr/(?<foo>.)(?<bar>.)(?<baz>.)/;
'abc' =~ $re;
say for keys %-;
```

See also [Tie::Hash::NamedCapture](http://p3rl.org/Tie::Hash::NamedCapture).

Comment: Hang on, isn't it `%+`?

Comment: Oh. perlvar has the difference.

Comment: I need to extract the names without having to match the regex

Comment: @abjY6U54: If you think you need to know the names of capture groups in a regex pattern that hasn't been applied to a string then you need to think again. It's something that can't be done in Perl, and with good reason. The values are available only after a *successful* match in the current lexical scope.